# beamer + minted most basic example fails (not the "fragile" problem)

Tags: beamer, minted

I'm failing to get the simplest possible beamer+minted example to work.  Here's my latex code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{minted}{python}
class X(object):
    pass
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'm running pdflatex like this

```
pdflatex -shell-escape main
```

and keep getting the following errors

```
! Argument of \@gobble has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14 \end{document}

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@gobble was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.14 \end{document}

! Argument of \@firstofone has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14 \end{document}

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@firstofone was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.14 \end{document}

! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@saveanother ->\let \beamer@savedif 
                                           =\ifbeamer@anotherslide 
l.14 \end{document}

! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 14.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.14 \end{document}

Runaway text?
rm "main.pyg/\def \gdef {}\def \let \next =\relax \gdef {}{\par }\def \ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.14 \end{document}

Runaway text?
rm "main.pyg/\def \gdef {}\def \let \next =\relax \gdef {}{\par }\def \ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.14 \end{document}

sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
[2] (./main.aux)
```

If I simply ignore those errors (e.g., by passing -interaction=nonstopmode), I do get a mostly good looking pdf document; the thing is that there is an extra page at the end containing the word "document" in it.

Any ideas what could be wrong?  I tried this example on two different linux systems, and got the same error both times.

Thanks.

Comment: Compiles like a charm here. Have you tried updating your TeX distribution?

Comment: I installed Linux Mint 15 a couple of weeks ago, so I guess I'm using a recent TeX distribution (I should double check though).

Comment: Voted unclear: unreproducible and no additional info from OP.